# KDE settings + locale - Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Tags: kde, locale

In the KDE-settings I can set my language and formats to different locales. It lets me choose between a bunch of them. In this list also is the locale `en_DE.UTF-8` (it's listed as `en_DE` though).
However as soon as I select this particular locale, I get into trouble. When I now run `locale`, I get the error

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

and the listed locales now do also show `en_DE.UTF-8` for some fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: After setting the locale in KDE's settings you have to manually double-check whether the set locale actually exists.

---

As it turns out KDE doesn't care what locales are actually installed on your system. It lets you use non-existing locales without any warning, which was exactly the case here. The locale `en_DE.UTF-8` didn't exist. This can be checked by running `locale -a` and searching for that particular locale in its output.

Therefore I had to go back to the KDE settings and change all `en_DE` settings to proper `de_DE` that I saw where present earlier. As soon as this was done (and the changes took effect after a fresh login), the problems where gone.

These settings are located at `/etc/locale.conf` and `~/.config/plasma-localerc`